# ModelState.IsValid is false due to hidden id field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

`ModelState.Isvalid` always shows false.

I have the below model

```
public class MyModel: MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int MyModelID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this viewmodel

```
public class MydatabaseVM
{
    public MyModel myMode { get; set; }
    public virtual Tab2 tab2 { get; set; }  
    public virtual Employee employee { get; set; }  
    public virtual Student student { get; set; }  
}
```

Am using this in a view

```
<div id="email" class="tab-pane fade">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyModel.MyModelID )
</div>
```

In my view I have the `MyModelID` in a hidden field, because I have several tabs in my page, and I want to retain the id to pass to the other tabs.

Once I save, I need the `MyModelID` in the hidden field. Here if I click on save and when it come to the post action the `ModelState.IsValid` always return false.

I tried removing the hidden field and it is coming as true. Can you help me what I am doing wrong here? My actual requirement is in a page i have multiple tabs and the main tab has some basic detials .When i save the data on the first tab the details should go to database and should generate and id .when i click on other tabs(using ajax and jquery) the is should pass to those and the data should save to the tables tab2

Comment: I think you have a typo. You have declared myMode to be of type MyModel, however, you are making a reference to model.MyModel. If MydatabaseWM is the Model of that view then that is an invalid reference.

Comment: Check `ModelState.Errors` to see what's wrong

Comment: @haim:error is with the id. The id need to be autogenerated from the database. If the modelstate is valid i should go and save the record then only i can get the id.

Comment: @Irb.: MydatabaseWM is the model for the view.can you brief me what error it is

Comment: Your `MyModelID` is an `int` type, so it automatically trigger the `Required` attribute. Your model binder problably isn't binding the `model.MyModel.MyModelID`, so it sends `null` to your POST action

Comment: In my first tab i have few details like name age etc and on save of that an id will be generated. That id i have to use in other tabs in the same page.This is my actual requirement.I am afraid what i am trying to achieve is possible with my code

Comment: Sidenote: If the id of the person is in the actual html, then the evil user could (depending on your app) change the id in the html and hence change the info of a completly different person.

Comment: @Thiago : ModelId will generate from database . On my controller post action if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {  here i call save the data to the table and retrieve the id.  } .So as you said my id is going to be null. How can i ignore the modelstate.isvalid to make true as my id is going to generate once it is valid

Comment: It looks like `MyEntity` is the actual data model ie a representation of the database table.  If that is the case, you could create a `MyEntity` ViewModel with a nullable Id field, because it's not going to work the way you're currently doing it

Comment: @mark:Sorry, i am not able to understand it. I am a beginner in mvc, may be that is what lacking me to understand

Comment: Sorry, I meant `MyModel`.  You've declared Id as Key, which to me indicates it's used to create a table for code-first migrations.  Is that the case?

Comment: yes, exactly. its an identity column there . i need to retain that id to oother tabs in the same page after save.that is the reason for maintaing in hidden field

Comment: `ModelState` is invalid because you do not have inputs for the `Forename` and `Surname` properties which have `[Required]` attributes. As always, use view models (do not use data models in views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelState` is invalid because your are using a data model in your view which contain 2 properties (`Forename` and `Surname`) which are decorated with the `[Required]` attribute and you have not posted values for them.

When you remove the hidden input, the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of `MydatabaseVM` but the value of `myMode` is the default (`null`) so there is nothing to validate.

But when you include the hidden input, its value is posted, which forces the `DefaultModelBinder` to initialize a new instance of `MyModel` and set the `MyModelID`. So now all properties of `MyModel` are validated and errors are added for the other 2 properties.

Rule 1: Always use [ViewModels](http://What%20is%20ViewModel%20in%20MVC?) when editing data. In your case it should be

```
public class MydatabaseVM
{
    public int MyModelID { get; set; }
    public virtual Tab2 tab2 { get; set; }  
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.HiddenFor( m=> m.MyModelID )
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen.I am providing value for surname and forename. It is failed in case of my hidden id.Clear about the modelbinder explanation provided. Thank you.My View model i want to include the public MyModel myMode { get; set; } class also

Comment: Are you saying you have hidden inputs in your view for `MyModel.Forename` and `MyModel.Surname`?

Comment: Do you mean to maintain multiple view model for each tab. ?

Comment: Nope. I am providing values for surname and forename. ..If i look at the modelstate error it is giving error for the MyModelID which is in the MyModel class

Comment: Please read my answer again carefully. If you have a hidden input for `MyModel.MyModelID` and you do not also include hidden inputs for `MyModel.Forename` and `MyModel.Surname` then `ModelState` **WILL** be invalid

Comment: So in my case i will add a modelid in my view model. Actually i have multiple tabs in a view , which all refers to a single viewmodel.MydatabaseVM .

Comment: You have not shown any code with respect to your tabs so I cant make any comment on that. All I can do is answer your question about why `ModelState` is invalid.

Comment: public class MydatabaseVM
    {
        public MyModel myMode { get; set; } //this has modelid already
        public virtual Tab2 tab2 { get; set; }  
 public virtual Employee employee { get; set; }  
 public virtual Student student { get; set; }  
    } Along with this do i need to  add public int MyModelID { get; set; } . So what about the modelid which is already there in the MyModel (mymode)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105351/discussion-between-jubi-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Modified my code in edit mode to invclude viewmodel.